# Map pointer with user's image and name in an Android map

Tags: android

When a user accesses the map in my app, I want to display his image and name and have them point to his location. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Create a map overlay where you override the draw method. Load user's image, draw it at coordinates you like. Draw his name as well. See [this sample](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/148/). Look at the [canvas API](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) for other methods.